# Getting values of all keys - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, key

So I am running this on my data:

$result = array_merge(array_intersect($x, array_keys($y)), array_diff(array_keys($y), $x))

Now I have a result $r that has all the keys I need, in the correct order.

Before I return result though, I want to get all the values for the keys as well and then return the new array that contains both the keys and values.

All the values that are needed are in $y. All the keys are in $result. But the keys and values are in different order basically. I could go through each one and search, but I'm afraid that may not be efficient? What's the most efficient way to do this?

result = array of keys in the right order

y = array of keys and values

Want to return: array of keys in the right order along with the corresponding values

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$keys = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$values = array('b'=>'B', 'a'=>'A', 'c'=>'C');
var_dump(array_merge(array_fill_keys($keys, false), $values));
```